# Does not show/retrieve PFObjects that were created by another Parse Installation user

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

I've been working on an app for months, and in the development stage it was having no problem retrieving info from the Parse backend. However, the second that I moved the app over to distribution and put in on the app store, I discovered that all the objects that someone would send me from their installation would not show up in my inbox. I am only able to see the objects I created in my inbox. Would anyone know possibly why I can't see objects that other users make on my app, and Vise Versa? Btw, this is through Xcode, Objective-C, and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Parse data browser, check the ACL on the objects you expect to see but don't.  You are probably creating objects that are not publicly readable.  You need to set a publicly readable acl on those objects.

```
PFObject *pfObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACL];
[acl setPublicReadAccess:true];
pfObject.ACL = acl;
[pfObject saveEventually];
```

You can also set up a default ACL somewhere in your app, possibly in your AppDelegate.m right after you intialize parse, so you don't need to create an ACL every time you create an object:

```
// Connect to Parse
[Parse setApplicationId:@"app-id" clientKey:@"client-key"];

// Set the default ACL
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

If that isn't your issue, post some code as well as the ACL for an object you expect to see but don't.